# DB rolls back on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to create a form with a series of checks to prevent duplicates during the simultaneous creation of three model records: one for the parent (assuming it doesn't exist), one for its child (assuming it doesn't exist), and one for a join table between the child and the User (to allow the User to have their own copy of the Song object).

1. In the current state of the code, The checks seemingly pass, but
   the server logs show `ROLLBACK`, and nothing gets saved
   to the database EXCEPT the parent object (artist).
2. When I try to use the ids of the object, I get the error `undefined method id for nil:NilClass`, or "couldn't find object without an ID".

The following code is in my controller:

```
    class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create

    @artist = Artist.find_by(name: params[:artist][:name].strip.titleize) #look for the artist

    @song = Song.find_by(title: params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:title].strip.titleize)


    if @artist.present? && @song.present?
      @user_song = current_user.user_songs.find(@song_id)

      if @user_song.present?
        render html: "THIS SONG IS ALREADY IN YOUR PLAYLIST"
        render action: :new
      else
        @user_song = UserSong.create(user_id: current_user.id, song_id: @song.id)
        redirect_to root_path
      end

    elsif @artist.present? && !@song.present?

      @song = @artist.songs.build(title: params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:title].strip.titleize, lyrics: params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:lyrics].strip)

      @user_song = UserSong.create(user_id: current_user.id, song_id: @song.id)
      redirect_to root_path

    elsif !@artist.present?

      @artist = Artist.create(name: params[:artist][:name].strip.titleize)

      @song = @artist.songs.build(title: params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:title].strip.titleize, lyrics: params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:lyrics].strip)

      @user_song = UserSong.create(user_id: current_user.id, song_id: @song.id)
      redirect_to root_path
    else 
      render html: "SOMETHING WENT WRONG. CONTACT ME TO LET ME KNOW IF YOU SEE THIS MESSAGE"
    end
  end


  def index
    @songs = Song.all
  end

  def new
    @artist = Artist.new
    @artist.songs.build
    @user_song = UserSong.new(user_id: current_user.id, song_id: @song_id)
  end

  def show
    @song_id = params["song_id"]
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    UserSong.where(:song_id => params[:id]).first.destroy
    flash[:success] = "The song has been from your playlist"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def edit
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    @artist = Artist.find(@song.artist_id)
  end

  def update
  end

  private
    def set_artist
      @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
    end

    def artist_params
      params.require(:artist).permit(:name, songs_attributes: [:id, :title, :lyrics])
    end
    def set_song
      @song = Song.find(params["song_id"])
    end
end
```

The models:

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :songs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :songs, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['lyrics'].blank? }
end

class Song < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :user_songs
  has_many :users, :through => :user_songs
end

class UserSong < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Sorry if I haven't abstracted enough. Not really sure how, given that there's no error message, just a rollback (without any validations present in any of the controllers).

Comment: This is why anybody with any experience with Rails will tell you not to dump tons of logic into controllers. There are myriad strategies for handling complex, nested, overly-constrained data, but StackOverflow isn't the place to come to learn about them. As it is, this question is going to be a doozy to answer because you haven't stripped this down far enough to make it easy to answer. If nothing else, I recommend removing the commented out code for clarity.

Comment: Gotcha. My apologies. I'll edit it down immediately

Comment: I tried my best to strip it down. Sorry again.

Comment: Use new instead of create , then do if user_song.save? else logger.info user_song.errors.full_messages to get full error message

Comment: after running `.create`, check that the record is `.persisted?` and if it's not, see `.errors.full_messages`

Comment: Still no luck -  I've been reading the active record validations guide, and @coreyward seems to be spot on: can't I just go to each of the model classes and write "validates :column, uniqueness: true"? Apparently a "database constraint" is also possible, although I have no idea what that actually means. I'll go try out the uniqueness thing and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @coreyward and his pointing out of the fat-model skinny-controller lemma (never knew that was a thing), I was able to cut the code down and arrive at a solution immediately. In my models, I used `validates_uniqueness_of` and `scope` in order to prevent duplication of records. In my controller, I used `find_or_create_by` to seal the deal.

To whom it may concern, the final code is as follows:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @artist = Artist.find_or_create_by(name: params[:artist][:name].strip.titleize)
    @song = @artist.songs.find_or_create_by(title: params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:title].strip.titleize) do |song|
      song.lyrics = params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:lyrics].strip
    end
    @user_song = current_user.user_songs.find_or_create_by(song_id: @song.id) do |user_id|
      user_id.user_id = current_user.id
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end



class Song < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, scope: :artist_id

  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :user_songs
  has_many :users, :through => :user_songs
end

class Artist < ApplicationRecord

  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  has_many :songs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :songs, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['lyrics'].blank? }
end


class UserSong < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :song_id, scope: :user_id

  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :user
end
```